# I have a json object and I want to push that object into the entries array. So the expected output is shown below. How to do this in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Need to insert the object in the entries array using **array_push** method of php where the value for **test_view_id** will be coming from another array. Can anyone please tell the syntax to do so.

```
$testViewId = array(12,13,14);
```

**sample object**

```
{
         "miscResourceProperties":{
            "test_view_id":12
         }
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
$data = {
   "eventStartTime":1656863552,
   "entries":[
      {
         "miscResourceProperties":{
            "test_view_id":12
         }
      },
      {
         "miscResourceProperties":{
            "test_view_id":13
         }
      },
      {
         "miscResourceProperties":{
            "test_view_id":14
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: The structure appears to be pretty fixed ... so ... can't you simply use string operations to assemble the JSON structure?

Comment: @arkascha Could you please share the relevant example it will be helpful. I'm new to PHP

Comment: ```array_push($info["entries"], array('miscResourceProperties' => array('test_view_id'=> '13')));```      I found this method is it correct? @arkascha

Comment: That way you add arrays, not objects.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. But basically if you're using PHP, convert the json to PHP array using `json_decode`, then push what you need, and convert it back to json using `json_encode`